# Working with Directories in Java/Android Application

Tags: java, android

I'd like to create a function to do the following: to replace an arbitrary string filled with potential "../" and "./" in the middle of it, to point to an absolute file name with the dots and extraneous slashes removed. ex: /data/data/org.hacktivity.datatemple/../../data/./org.hacktivity.datatemple/

```
private String validDirectory( String baseDirectory, String addOn ) {

    if ( baseDirectory + addOn ISN'T A VALID DIRECTORY ) {
        Toast(error);
        return baseDirectory;
    }
    else {
        // ex: /data/data/org.hacktivity.datatemple/../org.hacktivity.datatemple/ => /data/data/org.hacktivity.datatemple
        return TRIMMED VERSION OF baseDirectory + addOn;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for the `canonicalPath` of a `File` object. Use `getCaconicalPath()` or `getCanonocalFile()` to eliminate relative path elements:

```
File baseDir = new File(baseDirectory);
File addOnDir = new File(baseDir, addOn);

String canonicalPath = addOnDir.getCanonicalPath();

System.out.println(canonicalPath); // /data/data/org.hacktivity.datatemple
```